# AutoTyper with Multiline TextBox

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an auto typer that would type a message every 10 seconds.
It should send a total of 28 messages. Every message is on a different line in the MultiLine textbox.

It has the following layout:

- Multiline Textbox = TextBox
- Start Button = StartBtn
- Stop Button = StopBtn
- A timer with a 10500 interval (10.5 seconds) = TimerAuth

I combined some codes I found online.
It might look really stupid. But I am still a beginner :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AuthKeyTyper
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void StopBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void TimerAuth_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextReader read = new System.IO.StringReader(TextBox.Text);
        int rows = 27;
        string[] text1 = new string[rows];
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {

            text1[r] = read.ReadLine();
        }

        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[0] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[1] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[2] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[3] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[4] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[5] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[6] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[7] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[8] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[9] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[10] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[11] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[12] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[13] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[14] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[15] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[16] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[17] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[18] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[19] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[20] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[21] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[22] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[23] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[24] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[25] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[26] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("::auth " + text1[27] + "{enter}");
        TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Done");

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the particular issue you are having?

Comment: please show the attempt you've made at solving the problem yourself. SO won't write your solution for you.

Comment: So i first tried without the TimerAuth.Enabled = false;
        TimerAuth.Enabled = true; but this crashed to program. It is not working at all. I dont ask for a solution. I just need to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So first off. Thanks for all the down votes... I said I was a beginning member and I am interested in learning C#. After some digging and reading I discovered the function "await".

So I got rid of the timer and put the whole function into the start button_click event and used async.

So this became the form of the sendkey events:

```
SendKeys.Send(...)
await Task.Delay(10000)
SendKeys.Send(...)
await Task.Delay(10000)
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Well you are getting downvotes because you did not even ask a question.  We expect high quality questions here, so you'll need to try harder next time.